# Passing multiple PHP arrays to JavaScript on AJAX Success

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am having a hard time passing arrays from an PHP page to JavaScript using an AJAX request.

I will have to pass the information from multiple php arrays to javascript. I am aware I can use json_encode for this, however, I am having a hard time implementing this. The `$name` array don't seem to be getting passed, in addition, I will need all arrays to be passed to javascript not just `$name`.

I appreciate any suggestions with this.

Many thanks in advance!

This is what I tried for passing the `$name` array (code snippets):

PHP

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($results2)){
    $name[$i] = $row2['prod_name'];
    $price[$i] = $row2['price'];
    $upc[$i] = $row2['upc'];
    $quantity[$i] = $row2['quantity'];
}
echo json_encode($name);
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    url: "invoice-get-data.php?hotItems=1&getArrays=1",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: what does `alert(data)` gives? `undefined`?

Comment: you alert `name[0]`, yet you assign the successful return of the information to `data`...

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev, Thanks for the reply. Nothing gets alerted and no error messages...

Comment: @CaseyFlynn, thanks for the reply. Those are just code snippets, I also never defined `$results2` or any of the arrays. Please assume they are all defined and working, the code posted just relates to the passing of arrays from php to javascript.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend we can't assume anything since you don't show enough that is working. If they are just snippets and you think they should work, then show your actual code so it can be properly looked at.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend, you haven't defined $i, but you would definitely need to increment it within the body of that loop.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend if nothing gets alerted, it means that your AJAX request does not succeed. Try to see if `.error(someHandlerFunction)` will be hit.

Answer (score 2):

Back-end:

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($results2)){
    $name[] = $row2['prod_name'];
    $price[] = $row2['price'];
    $upc[] = $row2['upc'];
    $quantity[] = $row2['quantity'];
}
echo json_encode(array($name, $price, $upc, $quantity));
```

Front-end:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "invoice-get-data.php?hotItems=1&getArrays=1",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(data[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, nothing gets alerted, and no error messages either.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend that's because, again, you assigning the return to `data` on success, but try alerting `name`, which is not assigned.

Comment: @Jon, The problem described is after changing `name` to `data`.

Comment: Thanks you @zavg, however, still nothing ever gets alerted, no errors, even after adding `JSON.parse`

Comment: @AnchovyLegend What happens when you put the URL of your AJAX request in the URL? what output do you get?  Show that in your question?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend If nothing is alerted (even empty alert modal box) than may be invoice-get-data.php does not send AJAX-response (is it launched by AJAX-request? look what exectly it returns in Firebug or Chrome developen tools Network tab?)

Answer (score 0):

$i does not seem to be changed in the while loop, so the last value constantly gets overwritten by the new value. you can use:

```
$name = array(); //setup array
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($results2)){
    $name[] = $row2['prod_name']; //add to the end of the array
}
echo json_encode($name);
```

you could also use 'die' to echo your html code to be sure nothing else gets executed afterwards `die(json_encode($name));`

and your jquery returns the variable `data` so use `data`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "invoice-get-data.php?hotItems=1&getArrays=1",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, $i is not constant, those are just code snippets.

Comment: Or just add $row2 as a whole instead of all the elements in separate arrays.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend with all due respect, if you summarize, do at least summarize to a working sample. Your posted code contains at least 2 bugs unrelated to your question and apparently related to your 'snippeting'.

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted, it seems to answer the question correctly

Comment: Thanks for the edit, even after these modifications, still nothing gets alerted, and no errors are produces :/ Any suggestions?

Comment: might be the wrong url? try `/invoice-get-data.php?hotItems=1&getArrays=1`